# Java. Calculate the sum of 1 to 5

Tags: java, sum

I know this is a simple question that has probably been asked. But i have looked through the questions and done exactly as the answers there, but it still don't work. I really can't  understand why. I want the sum of 1 to 5 to be printed out, what have i done wrong? Here is the code:

```
public class no1
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        int number=0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++);
        {
            number+=i;
        }
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a simple question? You haven't asked a question.

Comment: @azurefrog sorry, completely missed the most important part, i have edited my post now, thanks!

Comment: You've got an extra `;` on the end of your for-loop, so that you're looping over no-op, and then execute the code in the braces only once.

Comment: @azurefrog thanks!

Comment: Just FYI, the sum of numbers from `1..N` is `N / 2 * (N + 1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove `;` from line `for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++);` Otherwise `for` body is not executed

Answer (score 0):

There is a semicolon behind the `for` loop, which should not be there. When you leave it out, the code will work.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    number += i;
}
```

Sidenote: you should begin the classname with an Uppercase letter (e. g. `No1`)